# injecting javascript into a textbox using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a code generator and I am wondering if I can inject javascript into a text box USING javscript.

I do not want the injected javascript to be executed, and I'm worried that the quotes in the string may cause errors.

For example, I want to inject this script:

```
$('#click').function(){
  $('#thing').html('<a href="user.php">User</a>');
}
```

into this textbox:

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="20" id="textbox">
</textarea>
```

Using javascript(jQuery)'s `.html()`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the value of the element:

```
$('#textbox').val("whatever, including JavaScript");
```

You'll have to make sure that the quote characters in the code you want to put into the `<textarea>` are quoted, but that's because you're expressing JavaScript source code in JavaScript and doesn't really have anything to do with the HTML element.

```
$('#textbox').val(
  "$('#click').function(){\n" +
  "  $('#thing').html('<a href=\"user.php\">User</a>');\n" +
  "}"
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use append function.

```
$('#click').function(){
$('#thing').append('<a href=\"user.php\">User</a>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use escape character sequences like \' or \" ?

Something like:

```
$('#textbox').html("$('#click').function(){
  $('#thing').html('<a href=\"user.php\">User</a>');
}");
```